# Keyword is really a complete address in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

The top keyword for my really small website (under 50 visits/month) is the complete address, with http:// and all. I doubt 14 people would go to a search engine and paste the address into the search box.

Does this kind of result has any special significance?

Comment: Is it happening in all browsers? Is the connection to your site slow or spotty? It's possible that some users are typing in your URL but the browser can't resolve it so it defaults to a search for that phrase which then pulls up your site, which then happens to load that time. I've seen this occasionally, but it seems unlikely to account for 30%.

Comment: @joshuahedlund not as far as Pingdom reports, no. And for mostly well-formed addresses, most browsers don't assume a search, but display a 404 page instead.

Answer (score 1):

With the shift by new web browsers like Google's own Chrome, and Mozilla's Firefox to create a [unified or smart address bar by giving it search capability](http://www.firefoxfacts.com/2008/09/10/search-from-the-address-bar-in-firefox/) this line is becoming blurred. Together with the fact that p[eople now thing that Google **IS** the internet](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o4MwTvtyrUQ), I'm not surprised by what you're seeing in your analytics.

Comment: Yes, it would explain it if it showed up once or twice. But not 30% of all visits. Also, people who think that google is the actual Internet wouldn't type "http colon slash slash w w w dot domain dot tld slash", would they? There are some results with incorrect and partial typings of my address and those make sense.

Comment: This is very common, as far as typing the http people type exactly what they see, so if it's on a business card or other print materials they will type it in, additionally if the link has been copied from an address bar and pasted into an email, many people rather then clicking the link in the email will copy and paste it into a search box (making it look as if they typed the whole thing in).

Comment: We are not even really online yet, just a filler page. Here, there's the link: http://www.jkai.com.br/. We are a small local band. Some of the vocalists may have spoken the name during a concert, but we have no printed materials at all to contain the address. Even so, GA records 43 visits in the past month and 14 as coming from google with this 'query'. No matter how technologically illiterate our followers may be, it's still a statistical anomaly that so many decided to type the full URL - with special chars and prefix included - the exact same way into Google

Comment: I can't show you for commercial reasons, but a website that I was recently responsible for, that got 100's of millions of visits per month saw this exact type of behaviour - so it's not just new sites, or small sites.